# Shadows in three.js : r71 vs r76

Tags: three.js, shadow

I'm building a 3D environment using three.js , `r76`.
I can't seem to get the shadows right.

In `r71`, I was pretty happy with the result, but it doesn't work the same in `r76`.

A fiddle to illustrate my problem:

`r71`: https://jsfiddle.net/sq2w15xy/

`r76`: https://jsfiddle.net/9uuq6s56/

As you can see, the shadow is black and pixelated in the newest revision.
What changed since then? What can I do the get the same smooth shadow as in `r71`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the light's [shadow.mapSize](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/LightShadow) must be set first as it's otherwise set to ( 512, 512) by default.

```
        spotlight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048; 
        spotlight.shadow.mapSize.height  = 2048;
```