# Three.js spotlight shadow not showing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get my head around three.js shadows. Currently have a scene set up with an object set to cast shadows and a floor set to receive them.

```
floor.receiveShadow = true;
```

Unfortunately the shadows aren't showing up. I'm sure i'm doing something daft. Any ideas would be great!

Example here: http://codepen.io/popmatik/pen/oLwPrk?editors=0010

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185944/shadows-in-three-js-r71-vs-r76

Comment: Not sure that's relevant here? @2pha

Comment: Are you asking me? Take a look at the fiddles in that question, it shows how to implement shadows

Comment: Try to insert `spotLight.shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 2500));` at row 34.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just noticed the question I linked to is using an older version of three.js and setting the shadows is different

Comment: That sorted it @mlkn thanks! Do I always have to add a LightShadow camera for spotlights then?

Comment: I got it to work with `spotLight.distance = 2000;`  Shadows have gotten quite hard to get right in the last couple of three.js releases

Comment: @RobLeach Projection matrix is needed for shadow mapping, but I think the moment and place it is set could vary with different releases. So looking into docs and source code makes sense. Also notice that you need Orthographic camera in case of directional light.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me (thanks @Ramil Kudashev):

```
let spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xfdf8d8, 0.3, 400, 0.8, 0.5, 1);
spotlight.target = <Some3DObjectToPointAt>;
spotlight.shadow = new THREE.SpotLightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, 1, 1, 250));
spotlight.castShadow = true;
//Add to scene somewhere
```

Ramil suggested using `THREE.LightShadow`, I had to pass `THREE.SpotLightShadow` (v0.110.0)

Tried changing camera `FOV` and `FAR`, but it did not seem to change the result.